# Error while installing web3@1.0.0-beta.26 on Windows 10

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I am getting the following error while installing web3@1.0.0-beta.26 on Windows 10.

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for web3-core@1.0.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'web3-eth'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tanuj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-18T05_50_02_703Z-debug.log
```

I have already successfully ran

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

but still getting error.

Comment: try running cmd as an administrator

Comment: @SanjaySB I did but still the same error.

Comment: What is the command line you are using? also 1.0.0-beta.26 is a quite old can you try with a more recent version?